# What are the basic preconditions that should be met to use database in the e-commerce based android application?

Tags: android

I am going to start development of an android application. This will be an online food ordering app. General flow of the app would be that user will first choose a location and based on that client will receive the list of around 300 available restaurants. On selecting a restaurant, client will receive the restaurant menu. Then checkout, payment etc etc. I am giving this info just to give an idea how much and what kind of data app would have.

My question is whether I should use sqlite database for such an app or should develop without it. What are the pros and cons of using a db for such an app. One pros I can think of is that on choosing a different location every time, the restaurants table and the menu table will have to be updated entirely. Not sure if this would be a good idea to use database in this case.

Please suggest.

Comment: store the information thats not frequently get updated like restaurant list for certain location

Comment: Where did you get the menu, price of your restaurant from? Outsource or your app itself which can let your customer register for their restaurant?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira There could be two ideas for this. Always use only one combination for location and restaurant list. For this case every time user chooses a different location, restaurant list table would be updated completely. Second is to have multiple combinations of location and restaurant list. This will require dynamic creation of restaurant list for that location and minor update on respective table as the location changes if the metadata changes. Data is going to be very dynamic in the app.